# Garbage Data output from a function

Tags: c++

I have recently been getting back into programming... Remaking and improving some of my old code... However I am running into some issues with some code output being correct until I get to a function which when called results in garbage data output and corrupts the char array I have. Hopefully someone can help with some of this...

Problem function: checkPath();

Problem occurrence: checkCommand();

[**program.cpp**]

```
#include "program.h"

program::program()
{
    SetConsoleTitle(WindowTitle);

    GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, curDirectory);
}

int program::run()
{
    do
    {
        printf("%s>", curDirectory);
        fgets(userInput, _countof(userInput), stdin);
    }while(!checkCommand(userInput));
    return 0;
}

bool program::checkCommand(char *input)
{
    char Cmd[100];
    char *SubCmd[100];
    ZeroMemory(Cmd, sizeof(Cmd));
    ZeroMemory(SubCmd, sizeof(SubCmd));

    strncpy(Cmd, input, strlen(input) - 1);

    char *tok = strtok((char *)Cmd, " ");
    strcpy(Cmd, tok);
    int i = 0;
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        if (i >= 1) SubCmd[i - 1] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    if (strcmp(Cmd, "exit") == 0) return true;
    if (strcmp(Cmd, "clearscreen") == 0 || strcmp(Cmd, "clear") == 0
        || strcmp(Cmd, "cls") == 0)
    {
        clearscreen();
    }
    else if (strcmp(Cmd, "ls") == 0 || strcmp(Cmd, "list") == 0)
    {
        char *list[500] = { NULL };
        getListFromPath(curDirectory, list);
        printf("List of files and directories:\n");
        int s = countBulkArray(list, 500);
        for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        {
            char *tmpFile = list[i];
            char type = 'X';
            char fileLocation[MAX_PATH] = { NULL };
            strcpy(fileLocation, curDirectory);
            strcat(fileLocation, "\\");
            strcat(fileLocation, (char *)tmpFile);
            if(checkPath(fileLocation) == false) type = 'D';
            else type = 'F';
            printf("%c - %s\n", type, list[i]);
        }
    }
    else if (strcmp(Cmd, "cd") == 0)
    {
        char tmpDir[MAX_PATH];
        char *Directories[MAX_PATH];
        char newDir[MAX_PATH];
        ZeroMemory(tmpDir, MAX_PATH);
        ZeroMemory(newDir, MAX_PATH);
        ZeroMemory(Directories, MAX_PATH);
        strncpy(tmpDir, curDirectory, strlen(curDirectory));
        char *dTok = strtok((char *)tmpDir, "\\\\");
        int i = 0;
        while (dTok != NULL)
        {
            Directories[i] = dTok;
            dTok = strtok(NULL, "\\\\");
            i++;
        }

        if(SubCmd[0] == NULL) return false;
        if (strcmp(SubCmd[0], "../") == 0 || strcmp(SubCmd[0], "..") == 0
            || strcmp(SubCmd[0], "..\\") == 0)
        {
            int sizeOf = countArray(Directories);
            if(sizeOf == 1) return false;
            for (int d = 0; d < sizeOf - 1; d++)
            {
                strcat(newDir, Directories[d]);
                strcat(newDir, "\\");
            }
        }

        if (checkPath(newDir) == 1)
        {
            strcpy(curDirectory, newDir);
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void program::getListFromPath(char path[MAX_PATH], char **out)
{
    char fileListString[1000] = { NULL };
    char fileListStr[1000] = { NULL };
    char *tok;

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    int i = 0;
    if ((dir = opendir(path)) != NULL)
    {
        while ((ent = readdir(dir)) != NULL)
        {
            if (i >= 2)
            {
                strcat(fileListStr, ent->d_name);
                strcat(fileListStr, ",");
            }
            i++;
        }
        closedir(dir);
        strncpy(fileListString, fileListStr, (countArray(fileListStr) - 1));
    }

    tok = strtok(fileListString, ",");
    i = 0;
    while (tok != NULL)
    {
        out[i] = tok;
        tok = strtok(NULL, ",");
        i++;
    }
}


bool program::checkPath(char *path)
{
    struct stat info;
    if(stat(path, &info) != 0) return false;
    else if(info.st_mode & S_IFDIR) return true;
    else return false;
}

int program::countBulkArray(char *tmp[], int arraySize)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++)
    {
        if(tmp[i] == 0) i = arraySize;
        size++;
    }
    return size - 1;
}

int program::countArray(char *tmp[MAX_PATH])
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++)
    {
        if(tmp[i] == NULL) i = MAX_PATH;
        else size++;
    }

    return size;
}

int program::countArray(char tmp[MAX_PATH])
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PATH; i++)
    {
        if (tmp[i] == NULL) i = MAX_PATH;
        else size++;
    }

    return size;
}

void program::clearscreen()
{
    COORD tl = { 0,0 };
    CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO s;
    HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(console, &s);
    DWORD written, cells = s.dwSize.X * s.dwSize.Y;
    FillConsoleOutputCharacter(console, ' ', cells, tl, &written);
    FillConsoleOutputAttribute(console, s.wAttributes, cells, tl, &written);
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(console, tl);
}


program::~program()
{
}
```

[**program.h**]

```
#pragma once
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <dirent.h>

class program
{
public:
    program();
    ~program();
    int run();

private:
    const char *WindowTitle = "Command Prompt";
    void clearscreen();

    bool checkCommand(char *cmd);
    int countArray(char *tmp[MAX_PATH]);
    int countArray(char tmp[MAX_PATH]);
    int countBulkArray(char *tmp[], int arraySize);
    bool checkPath(char *path);
    void getListFromPath(char path[MAX_PATH], char **out);

    char curDirectory[MAX_PATH];
    char userInput[1000];
};
```

Garbage data with function being ran: https://puu.sh/Fc3ss/2ad35685e2.png
Correct data output without function being ran: https://puu.sh/Fc3t1/1d9988299a.png

Comment: Instead of learning from your old code, I suggest getting a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).  C++ has change **a lot** and there are much better ways of doing things now.  Also, there is a lot of C in your C++ code.  You should be using C++ idioms in C++ code instead of C ones.

Comment: And the shown code is full of error-prone and flawed logic, with bounds-checking failures all over the places. There are dozens of possible places that fail to do proper bounds checking, run off past the end of the array, and generally creating garbage of this kind. I say it's not worth trying to figure out where things break, but rather scrap this and rewrite it from scratch as modern, clean, C++ code.

Comment: One problem you're having is with `getListFromPath`.  You're returning pointers to the local `fileListString` variable, which goes out of scope and is destroyed when you return from the function.

Comment: For example, all of the character arrays should be replaced with `std::string` unless you have a really good reason for the array (or feel you need to suffer).